# Confidence interval on chi-squared values

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test

I am doing a grid search for model fits to data. At each point of the grid (let's say a 2d parameter space) I have a value for the statistic

$\chi^{2} = \sum_{i}\frac{(O_{i}-E_{i})^{2}}{dO_{i}^{2}}$

where $O_i$ are observed data points, $E_i$ the model values and $dO_i$ the (generally different) errors on the observed values.

How do I find a confidence interval (let's say the 68% interval) around the minimum value that I find?

To my understanding, standard $\chi^{2}$ only works if the errors are approximately Poissonian.

Comment: I think that the assumption is that $O_i$ is Poisson and $\chi^2=\sum_i \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$?

Comment: Right. But what if that condition is not met? I'm supposing one has to resort to sampling methods.

Comment: Your formula for $\chi^2$ is very different from the one in my comment, the denominator is very ''strange'', it should be $E_i$.  Usually, if the $E_i$ are all over 5 then the variable can be approximated well by $\chi^2$.

Comment: If the denominator is replaced by $\mathrm{Var}(O_i)$ it would be more general. My question is whose confidence interval you want to get?

Comment: Ultimately a confidence interval for the two estimated parameters. This should follow from a contour in the $\chi^{2}$-space as in the following paper, the only difference being that the errors in the paper are manifestly Poissonian and mine are not: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1976ApJ...210..642A&amp;data_type=PDF_HIGH&amp;whole_paper=YES&amp;type=PRINTER&amp;filetype=.pdf

Comment: They don't have to be Poissonian, the point is that it is a sum of squares of standard normal variables.  In the case of a Poisson random variable $\frac{O_i-E_i}{\sqrt{E_i}}$ is  (asymptotically) standard normal. So if you subtract the mean and devide by the standard deviation and then sum these squares, then you have asymptically a $\chi^2$, also for non-Poisson (you have to find out the degrees of freedom).  @a_statistician made a simiar remark. So your confidence interval will look like an ellips in the two-dimensional case.

Answer (score 4):

$\chi^2$ is a valid statistic for any data where you expect the errors to be normally distributed. It is commonly used for counting data, where you expect poisson errors of order $\sqrt{O_i}$ (which become gaussian in the large count limit), but as @a_statistician notes the more general formula is
$$\chi^2 = \sum_i\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{Var(O_i)}$$.

Restating your problem, it sounds like you have some model parameters, let's call them $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which are used to predict $E_i(\alpha,\beta)$, and some observed values $O_i$, along with some prediction about the size of errors, $Var(O_i)$. Therefore you can calculate $\chi^2(\alpha,\beta)$ as a function of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

You have then (correctly) estimated $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by minimizing this function, and now want to obtain the confidence intervals for these estimates. As [the paper you linked](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1976ApJ...210..642A&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf) explains, one way to do this is to consider the parameters themselves to be free, and lookup to corresponding cumulative-probability function for a chi-squared distribution with that number of degrees of freedom (using [one of the many handy tables available online](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/tbl-chi.html)).

For the example you gave, with two parameters, the 95% cumulative probability point is 5.991 (corresponding to (2,0.05) on the linked table). Therefore, one would call the 95% confidence region the set of all points $(\alpha, \beta)$ in parameter space such that

$$\chi^2(\alpha,\beta) - \chi^2_{min} < 5.991$$

For a good, well-constrained model, this should give you something fairly nice, like an ellipse. This ellipse corresponds to the covariance matrix for your parameters, as [this article](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/draw-error-ellipse-representing-covariance-matrix/) nicely explains, and therefore standard errors and other commonly used measures of uncertainty.